# Cockpit 283 Red Hat

Tags: rhel, cockpit

Is it possible to install the last version of cockpit 283 on RHEL 7.9?
Following the steps from official webpage I get 195 all the time https://cockpit-project.org/running.html#rhel

```
yum update cockpit
```

Can't find any package to update.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess RHEL is too old (9 years now). v195 corresponds somewhat with the end of its "Production 1" phase.

Comment: Saw the same version on an up-to-date CentOS 7 today (managed appliance) and wondered the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've found out that 195 was the last for RHEL 7.9. The topic can be closed.